# Development vs Distribution versions are different- iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, dictionary

I have recently published my app in Appstore. However one function which is adding pin on the map by calling NSURL that is very critical for my application is not functioning in Appstore version.
I have tested my application on real devices, it is working. Howoever, once I created iPA for adhoc distribution, this functionality is not working.

I have just created a separete thread for adding pin on the map, but it is not working. Here is the code portion for addin pin on the map:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration=0.7;
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
}

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    if(gestureRecognizer.state!=UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    return;
    CGPoint touchPoint=[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate=[self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint     toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
    lati=touchMapCoordinate.latitude;
    longi=touchMapCoordinate.longitude;
    NSString *newPinPoint2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", touchMapCoordinate.latitude, touchMapCoordinate.longitude];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(annotationHTTPRequest:) toTarget:self withObject:newPinPoint2];// added separate thread
    //[self annotationHTTPRequest:newPinPoint2];// commented our

   }

-(void)annotationHTTPRequest:(NSString*)theNewPoint
{

    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:url4];
    NSString *newP=theNewPoint;
    // 4
    __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1];
    [request1 setCompletionBlock:^{
        responseString = [request1 responseString];
        [self annotationJSON:responseString second:newP ];

    }];
    [request1 setFailedBlock:^{

        NSError *error=[request1 error];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
    [request1 startAsynchronous];


}
```

Comment: That's an odd thing to have stop working. Have you tried keeping everything in the same thread and testing the IPA you get that way to see if it still works?

Comment: Yes originally, everything was on the same thread as you seen in the code part which I commented out and implemented newthread.

Comment: it would be interesting to know what annotationHTTPRequest: does. does it work with dispatch_async()?

Comment: @Hello Martin, please see updated version of my question